# Print char received from socket one at a time

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I am working on a program and I have to send one char at a time through a socket. The connection work fine and the chars are sending but when I have to print them to stdout, I cant manage to print them without a newline.

```
for ( ; ; ) {
            nb = select(connfd+1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if (nb<=0) {
                printf("Error\n");
            }else{
                if (FD_ISSET(connfd, &read_set)) {
                    char buff[2];
                    nb = read(connfd, buff, 4096);
                    if (nb < 0){
                        printf("The client disconected\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    printf("%s\n",buff); // this prints them with a new line between each char.Removing the \n will make it work only by hitting enter
                    //fputs(buff,stdout); //does the same as printf without \n
                }
```

One more mention: the client send chars without waiting for ENTER from stdin.

Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: `putc(nb); flush();` mayhaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Don't lie to `read` - it tends to nearly always lead to BAD things:

```
                char buff[2];
                nb = read(connfd, buff, 4096);
```

This should be:
                    char buff[2];
                    nb = read(connfd, buff, 1);

2) You need to terminate the string:

```
buff[1] = 0;
```

2a) `printf("%s", buff)` will not actually display anything, because there is no newline to force the buffered data to be actually written to the screen - use `fflush(stdout);` to force it.

3) Reading characters without waiting for "enter" is not possible in standard C++ (or C). May I suggest you look at the `ncurses` package of functions?

Comment: +1 `ncurses` and `pdcurses` are great libraries for unbuffered input.

Comment: As for 3) I managed to do that by 
termios tos;
tcgetattr(0, &tos);
tos.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; // or cfmakeraw(&tos) but it's not POSIX
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &tos);

Comment: Yes, you can of course use system-specific functionality to read input without wating for "enter" - the problem is that even within different flavours if Unix it has been known to vary. One of the many  "curses" libraries will allow you to do much more than just read input without waiting, and it will work on all platforms that the particular package supports.

Answer (score 2):

```
                printf("%s\n",buff);
```

The `%s` format specifier is *only* for C-style strings. Since `buff` is not a C-style string, this is wrong. Also:

```
                char buff[2];
                nb = read(connfd, buff, 4096);
```

How can you read up to 4096 characters into a buffer that's only big enough for 2? You probably want:

```
                char buff[4096];
                nb = read(connfd, buff, 4096);
                if (nb < 0){
                    printf("The client disconected\n");
                    break;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < nb; ++i)
                   putchar(buff[i]);
                fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: I would use `printf("%.*s", nb, buff)` instead of a `putchar()` loop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Will that stop on a zero byte?

Comment: yes, since it is specifying a *maximum* length only, so a null could terminate it earlier. You could try using `printf("%*.*s", nb, nb, buff)` instead, which species both *minimum* and *maximum* lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the buffer.  After your `printf` call, also call `fflush(stdout)`.

Also, since you are trying to print 1 character at a time, you have a few other problems:

```
char buff; // you wanted to read 1 character at a time
nb = read(connfd, &buff, 1); 
if (nb < 1)
{
    printf("The client disconected\n");
    break;
}
printf("%c", buff);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: I think alternatively you can also change the buffering mechanism, depending on the OS. `fflush` seems like the way to go, though